# Magento Community Edition 1.9 End of life

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

Our current platform, Magento Community Edition 1.9, is slated to receive security patches until June of 2020, according to the documentation on Magento’s website

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020
https://magento.com/sites/default/files/magento-open-source-software-maintenance-policy.pdf

I have heard from alternate sources that Magento CE 1.9 will only be supported until October of this year (though I find that highly suspect). Secondly, what would a transition to a Magento Open Source 2.x version look like down the road when 1.9 eventually reaches end of support?

Comment: The 2018 end of life date was announced originally but eventually canceled. June 2020 is currently the official end of life. You can find a few thoughts on migrating to Magento 2 (or not) on our blog: https://www.integer-net.com/magento-1-or-magento-2-a-guidebook/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things that you will need to do for migration from your Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x

1.)Theme Migration: You have to either buy a similar theme if available or else develop your own theme.

2.)Extension Migration: Find if any similar functionality module is availbe for Magento 2.x, if not availabe have to develop it.

3.)Customization Migration: All the customizations that you made again need to rewritten if not compatible if with Magento 2.x, there is a tool for it: https://github.com/magento/code-migration

4.)Data migration: This step involves migrating the database from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x database. There is a tool for it from Magento 2. It migrates the data into 3 steps: Settings,Data,Delta . (Link for more information:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html)

You will need a developer or developer's who have atleast few months of experience on Magento 2.